# Percentage (%) in the joomla blog post url breaking site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

Anyone know how to redirect

> domain/blog/208-%-top.html

To:

> domain/blog/208-top.html

in Joomla?

None of the below works:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/208-%-top.html$ 208-top.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/208-\%-top.html$ 208-top.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/208-.*-top.html$ 208-top.html [R=301,L]
```

It works if: url has %20 or %25 and have below in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^blog/208-%20-top.html$ 208-top.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/208-%25-top.html$ 208-top.html [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is blog post has % only. Is there any work around to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL:

```
domain.com/blog/208-%-top.html
```

is indeed an **invalid URL** and would cause HTTP 400 (Bad Request) error in your Apache logs.

As you noted too that any of these 2 URLs are valid:

```
domain.com/blog/208-%20-top.html
```

OR

```
domain.com/blog/208-%25-top.html
```

And both of them will work well with this Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/208-\%-top\.html$ blog/208-top.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be because apache isn't properly identifying your rewrite target as a URL-path, you'll need to include the full path to fix that.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/208-\%-top.html$ /blog/208-top.html [R=301,L]
```